# Function is not usable as a 'constexpr' function

Tags: c++, c++20

Take a look at the following code

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct basic_type {
  using type = T;
};

consteval auto foo(auto p, auto x) noexcept {
  if constexpr (p(x)) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

int main() {
    // This compiles
    return foo(
        []<typename T>(basic_type<T>) 
        { 
            return std::is_integral_v<T>; 
        }, 
        basic_type<int>{});

    // This gives "x is not a constant expression"
    /*return foo(
        []<typename T>(T) 
        { 
            return std::is_integral_v<std::decay_t<T>>; 
        }, 
        0);*/
}
```

The first return statement compiles just fine on latest gcc trunk, while the second one does not compile, with the error message:

```
source>: In instantiation of 'consteval auto foo(auto:1, auto:2) [with auto:1 = main()::<lambda(T)>; auto:2 = int]':
<source>:26:12:   required from here
<source>:9:3: error: 'x' is not a constant expression
    9 |   if constexpr (p(x)) {
      |   ^~
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:26:19: error: 'consteval auto foo(auto:1, auto:2) [with auto:1 = main()::<lambda(T)>; auto:2 = int]' called in a constant expression
   26 |         return foo(
      |                ~~~^
   27 |                 []<typename T>(T)
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   28 |                 {
      |                 ~  
   29 |                         return std::is_integral_v<std::decay_t<T>>;
      |                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   30 |                 },
      |                 ~~ 
   31 |                 0);
      |                 ~~ 
<source>:8:16: note: 'consteval auto foo(auto:1, auto:2) [with auto:1 = main()::<lambda(T)>; auto:2 = int]' is not usable as a 'constexpr' function because:
    8 | consteval auto foo(auto p, auto x) noexcept {
      |                ^~~
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Here's a godbolt link
https://godbolt.org/z/71rbWob4e

**EDIT**

As requested, here's foo without auto parameters:

```cpp
template<typename Predicate, typename T>
consteval auto foo(Predicate p, T x) noexcept {
  if constexpr (p(x)) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Error Message looks like this:

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'consteval auto foo(Predicate, T) [with Predicate = main()::<lambda(T)>; T = int]':
<source>:27:15:   required from here
<source>:10:3: error: 'x' is not a constant expression
   10 |   if constexpr (p(x)) {
      |   ^~
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:27:15: error: 'consteval auto foo(Predicate, T) [with Predicate = main()::<lambda(T)>; T = int]' called in a constant expression
   27 |     return foo(
      |            ~~~^
   28 |         []<typename T>(T)
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   29 |         {
      |         ~      
   30 |             return std::is_integral_v<std::decay_t<T>>;
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   31 |         },
      |         ~~     
   32 |         0);
      |         ~~     
<source>:9:16: note: 'consteval auto foo(Predicate, T) [with Predicate = main()::<lambda(T)>; T = int]' is not usable as a 'constexpr' function because:
    9 | consteval auto foo(Predicate p, T x) noexcept {
      |
```

Comment: fwiw, the difference seems to be `0` vs `basic_type<int>{}` not `std::decay_t<T>` vs `T` (https://godbolt.org/z/5Mfe14MxW)

Comment: Given that all compilers (gcc, clang, msvc) have the same result and somewhat weird rules w.r.t. `if constexpr` I'm inclined to believe that the error is correct (but not 100% sure). Can you try to rewrite your foo replacing `auto` parameters with actual template arguments? Likely it'd make it clearer.

Comment: I added the function without auto parameters @DanM.

Comment: `consteval` and `constexpr` function can have non-compile-time arguments. It means that compiler makes most general assumptions when compiling this function. And this assumption is that arguments are non-compile-time. It means that compiler can't guarantee that your `if-constexpr` is always compile-time, hence the error about it. If you place all your arguments as template `auto` parameters of your function then it should compile well.

Comment: but it does not actually depend on the value you pass in, only the type of the value, which is always known at compile-time?

Comment: @Yamahari I don't remember for sure but it seems to me that `constexpr` function becomes non-compile-time (i.e. non-constexpr) as soon as at least one param is non-compile-time. And your lambda is constexpr function, which becomes non-constexpr because you pass non-compile-time param. It means formally that your lambda result is non-compile-time value, hence `if-constexpr` can't be used with it.

Comment: @Arty: but why it passes for first variant?

Comment: @Jarod42 Don't know for sure but maybe for some reason in first case compiler can 100% guarantee somehow that evaluated lambda returns compile-time value.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In order to evaluate this:

```cpp
  if constexpr (p(x)) {
```

We need for `p(x)` to be a constant expression. The rules for whether something qualifies as a constant expression or not are based on a list of things that you're not allowed to do.

When `x` is a `basic_type<int>` and `p` is a function that takes a `basic_type<int>` by value, there are simply no rules that we are violating. This is an empty type, so copying it (as we're doing here) doesn't actually involve any kind of read. This just works.

---

But when `x` is an `int` and `p` is a function that takes an `int` by value, this also requires copying `x` but this time it involves reading the value of `x`. Because, of course, gotta initialize the parameter somehow. And this *does* run afoul of a rule: [[expr.const]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.8) says we're not allowed to perform:

> an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion unless it is applied to
>
> - a non-volatile glvalue that refers to an object that is usable in constant expressions, or
> - a non-volatile glvalue of literal type that refers to a non-volatile object whose lifetime began within the evaluation of E;

An lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is what happens when we read the value of a variable, and neither of those bullets apply. It doesn't matter here that you don't actually care what the value is, since `p` doesn't use it. In order to be able to even invoke `p`, you have to copy `x`, and you're not allowed to do that. Hence the error.

---

However, your lambda here doesn't actually need the value, just the type, so you could instead write this:

```cpp
    return foo(
        []<typename T>(T const&) 
        { 
            return std::is_integral_v<std::decay_t<T>>; 
        }, 
        0);
```

Now we're no longer copying `x` into the lambda, since the lambda no longer takes by value - it takes by reference. As a result, we're not violating the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion rule (or any other rule) and this is now a valid constant expression.

---

Then, as a bonus, if you change `foo` to take `x` by reference (because, again, you don't actually care about the value, so why not):

```cpp
consteval auto foo(auto p, auto const& x) noexcept {
  if constexpr (p(x)) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Then *both* variants become ill-formed. Both the `basic_type<int>` and `int` versions (regardless of whether you take the `int` by value or by reference). For more on this case, see [the constexpr array size problem](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2020/02/05/constexpr-array-size/) which I'm currently trying to resolve with [P2280](https://wg21.link/p2280).